# Is TIdHTTP threadsafe?

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

I'm using `TIdHTTP` in my class to handle web APIs (`TWebAPI`). Since it might happen that this class is used in a `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event handler, I need to make sure that `TWebAPI`is thread safe.

Do I need to wrap a `PUT`/`GET`/`POST` inside a `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`?

EDIT: Code-Sample

TWebAPI

```
TWebAPI=class(TObject)
 FSocket:TidHTTP;
end;

procedure TWebAPI.Send;
Var
 Response:TSTringStream;
begin
 FSocket.Get(fURL,Response);
end;
```

Main Program

```
TMain=class(TForm)
 Server:TidHTTPServer;
 WebAPI:TWebAPI;
end;

procedure TMain.ServerCommandGet(....)
begin
 WebAPI.Send;
end;
```

So my WebAPI would be used in different threads on each command the server gets. SHould I use the CriticalSection in TMain, or implement it in TWebAPI like this?

```
TWebAPI=class(TObject)
 FSocket:TidHTTP;
 FLock:TCriticalSection;
end;

procedure TWebAPI.Send;
Var
 Response:TSTringStream;
begin
 FLock.Aquire;
 try
   FSocket.Get(fURL,Response);
 finally
   FLock.Release;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: It depends on how you use it. You did not show any code. Like most other classes, if you share a `TIdHTTP` object across thread boundaries, then yes, you need to sync access to it. Otherwise, no, you do not.  Please provide a [mcve] that you are concerned about, and someone can tell you if it is threadsafe or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, code added :-)

Comment: You are sharing a single `TIdHTTP` across multiple threasd, so yes, you would need to lock access to it on each HTTP operation you want to perform. Is there a reason why you are using a single `TIdHTTP` in this manner, and not letting each `TIdTCPServer` thread use its own local `TIdHTTP` instead?

Comment: Yes, TwebAPI uses OAuth and I don't want to do it every time.

Comment: You don't need to reuse a single `TIdHTTP` just to reuse credentials across multiple HTTP requests. Use 1 `TIdHTTP` to grab the credentials one time and save them, and then you can assign the saved credentials to other `TIdHTTP` objects as needed.  So, I'm still in the mindset that each server thread should be using its own local `TIdHTTP`, and you sync only the OAuth login between them.

Comment: I'll look into that, thx!

Comment: Would I also recreate the (SSL)IOHandler every time new, or use a shared one?

Comment: You can't share an `(SSL)IOHandler` between multiple clients *simultaneously*, since it represents a single TCP connection. But, if you have multiple requests going to the same server, it might make sense to share an `(SSL)IOHandler` as long as the requests are not performed *simultaneously*.  For instance, you could create a small pool of `(SSL)IOHandler` objects, and then pull one out of the pool when you need to make a request, and put it back in the pool when finished. Of course, you could do the same thing with `TIdHTTP` objects, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single TIdHTTP could be protected by a `TCriticalSection` or `TMonitor`. There is no R/W involved, so don't use `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` - just a mutex/lock. But if you use a single TIdHTTP you will need a mutex/lock, so all HTTP calls will be serialized, which may be not a good idea on a multi-threaded server.

I would maintain one connection per thread, or write a connection pool. Perhaps just a given TIdHTTP each time may not be too bad. At least it will be safe and there will be room for improvement later on. Reopening a TCP/HTTP connection is quick in practice.

Comment: I'm currently only using `TMREWS`for everything. Is it "just" performance that gets lost when using it all the time, or are there any other cavets?

Comment: You *can* use `TMREWSync`, but you would have to use only its write lock for adequate protection, which kind of defeats the purpose of using `TMREWSync` in the first place.  A `TCriticalSection` or `TMonitor`, or even a Win32 Slim R/W Lock, would be more efficient.